# How to combine dataframe rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have the following code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

fileName= input("Enter file name here (Case Sensitve) > ")
df = pd.read_excel(fileName +'.xlsx', sheetname=None, ignore_index=True)
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fileName +'.xlsx')
SystemCount= len(xl.sheet_names)
df1 = pd.DataFrame([])

for y in range(1, int(SystemCount)+ 1): 
    df = pd.read_excel(xl,'System ' + str(y))
    df['System {0}'.format(y)] = "1"    
    df1 = df1.append(df)

df1 = df1.sort_values(['Email'])
df = df1['Email'].value_counts()
df1['Count'] = df1.groupby('Email')['Email'].transform('count')

print(df1)
```

Which prints something like this:

```
Email                       System 1 System 2 System 3 System 4  Count
test_1_@test.com             NaN      1        NaN      NaN      1 
test_2_@test.com             NaN      NaN      1        NaN      3
test_2_@test.com             1        NaN      NaN      NaN      3
test_2_@test.com             NaN      NaN      NaN      1        3
test_3_@test.com             NaN      1        NaN      NaN      1
test_4_@test.com             NaN      NaN      1        NaN      1
test_5_@test.com             1        NaN      NaN      NaN      3
test_5_@test.com             NaN      NaN      1        NaN      3  
test_5_@test.com             NaN      NaN      NaN      1        3
```

How do I combine this, so the email only shows once, with all marked systems?
I would like the output to look like this:

```
     System1  System2  System3  System4  Count
Email                                                      
test_1_@test.com      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      1
test_2_@test.com      1.0      0.0      1.0      1.0      3
test_3_@test.com      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      1
test_4_@test.com      0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0      1
test_5_@test.com      1.0      0.0      1.0      1.0      3
```

Comment: show us your expected output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The question has been updated, thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it clearly

```
    df1=df1.apply(lambda x : pd.to_numeric(x,errors='ignore'))
    d=dict(zip(df1.columns[1:],['sum']*df1.columns[1:].str.contains('System').sum()+['first']))
    df1.fillna(0).groupby('Email').agg(d)
    Out[95]: 
                      System1  System2  System3  System4  Count
    Email                                                      
    test_1_@test.com      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      1
    test_2_@test.com      1.0      0.0      1.0      1.0      3
    test_3_@test.com      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      1
    test_4_@test.com      0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0      1
    test_5_@test.com      1.0      0.0      1.0      1.0      3
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the out put I am looking for, but when I use the code you provided, I get the following error : 'Series' has no attribute 'columns'. I inserted the code right before the print line, is that the correct spot?

Comment: @bemurr187 you should change df to df1 :-) in my code

Comment: Thank you! I did but I was given this error now unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @bemurr187  do you have dtype str for those number ?

Comment: I don't believe so, everything I have is posted into the question. How would I do that?

Comment: @bemurr187 you can apply , pd.to_numeric to your data, I guess 1 in your df1 is '1'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165175/discussion-between-bemurr187-and-wen).

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier to get help if you would post code to generate your input data.

But you probably want a `GroupBy`:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('Email').sum()
```

Comment: Hi sorry, I just uploaded what the output should look like

Comment: The counts in the example above would be summed up wrong because each row has the count. instead
    df1 = df1.fillna(0)
    df2 = df1.groupby('Email').max()